# How to change the id of any tag wiht javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django

Html Code:-

```html
{% for post in posts %}
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2><a id="post_title" class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'blog-profile' name=post.author %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
            <div class="float-right">
                <small class="text-muted">Category</small>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;">
                <img style="height:19px; width:18px;" src="{% static "blog/viewicon.png" %}">
                    <p style="float: right; display: inline !important;" id="ViewCount">
                    
                    </p>
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content|truncatechars:200|safe }}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function changeid ()
        {
        var e = document.getElementById('post_title');
        e.id = 'post_title_1';
        var e = document.getElementById('ViewCount');
        e.id = 'ViewCount_1';
        }
    </script>

</article>
{% endfor %}
```

I am trying to change the id of those two tags but, this script doesn't seem to work, or it's been not exected. I want to change that id because I want to insert some data to them from the server. Since we can't have the same id the data which I am trying to embed is embedded by defaut to only the first run of the loop.

Comment: where are you calling `changeid()` function ?

Comment: use `setAttribute` to set the new `id` of your element. Also make sure you are calling that function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the id in each iteration using JavaScript. You can achieve the same using Django's inbuilt `forloop.counter` template tag.

( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for )

So in your case, it would be something like:

```html
{% for post in posts %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h2><a id="post_title_{{ forloop.counter }}" class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'blog-profile' name=post.author %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
      <div class="float-right">
        <small class="text-muted">Category</small>
        <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
      </div>
      <div style="float:right;">
        <img style="height:19px; width:18px;" src="{% static " blog/viewicon.png " %}">
        <p style="float: right; display: inline !important;" id="ViewCount__{{ forloop.counter }}">

        </p>
        </img>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="article-content">{{ post.content|truncatechars:200|safe }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `document.getElementById('footer').setAttribute('id','post_title_1')` 
Also Make sure you are calling the `changeid()` function

```html
{% for post in posts %}
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2><a id="post_title" class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'blog-profile' name=post.author %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
            <div class="float-right">
                <small class="text-muted">Category</small>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;">
                <img style="height:19px; width:18px;" src="{% static "blog/viewicon.png" %}">
                    <p style="float: right; display: inline !important;" id="ViewCount">
                    
                    </p>
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content|truncatechars:200|safe }}</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function changeid ()
        {
        document.getElementById('post_title').setAttribute('id','post_title_1');
        document.getElementById('ViewCount').setAttribute('id','ViewCount_1')
        }
    </script>

</article>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `IIFE` - An IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined.

```
<script>
  (() => {
    let a = document.getElementById('post_title');
    a.setAttribute("id", 'post_title_1'); 
    let b = document.getElementById('ViewCount');
    b.setAttribute("id", 'ViewCount_1'); 
  })();
</script>
```